# Drag&Drop for Multiple Selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

i have a little Problem with my Drag & Drop function. The Drag & Drop function works fine for only one Item.. then i tried to make it work for multiple itemSelection, but i don't get it.

My xaml contains 2 ListViews, first i show you my List where the Items will be displayed to drag it to the other ListView:

```
<ListView Name="lvVaCodes" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="lvVaCodes_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="lvVaCodes_MouseMove" SelectionMode="Multiple"  >
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListView>
```

Here is my ListView, where the dropped items should be shown:

```
<ListView Name="lvDebitor" Drop="lvDebitor_Drop" MinHeight="100" AllowDrop="True">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

Here are my Events:

```
    private void lvVaCodes_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dragAction = true;
    }

    private void lvVaCodes_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dragAction == true && Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            _lastListView = sender as ListView;

            if (_lastListView != null && _lastListView.SelectedItems != null && _lastListView.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_lastListView, new DataObject("ObservableCollectionViewItemData", _lastListView.SelectedItems), DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void lvDebitor_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        IList items = e.Data.GetData("ObservableCollectionViewItemData") as IList;

        if (items == null || _lastListView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for(int i=0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            _vaCodesDeb.Add((TodoItem)items[i]);
            _vaCodes.Remove((TodoItem)items[i]);
        }
        dragAction = false;            
    }

    private void lvVess_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        IList items = e.Data.GetData("ObservableCollectionViewItemData") as IList;

        if (items == null || _lastListView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            _vaCodesVess.Add((TodoItem)items[i]);
            _vaCodes.Remove((TodoItem)items[i]);
        }
        dragAction = false;
    }
```

Can anybody tell me, why it doesn't work? Only one Item will be dragged & dropped.

Comment: Any debug info? it crashed or just didn't paste the items?

Comment: Try doing 2 loops, 1 for add and another one for remove. Maybe the remove is modifying the index or something.

Comment: it doesn't crash. It only drag and drop the last item i clicked.

Comment: I tried it with 2 loops. The same.

Comment: Can you post some debug info? number of iterations of the loop, content of the `items[]` in each case, etc.

Comment: May be you could add som Debug.WriteLine( ...) to show how many items there are in the SelectedItems  before DragDrop.DoDragDrop(_lastListView, new DataObject("ObservableCollectionViewItemData", _lastListView.SelectedItems), DragDropEffects.Move);

Comment: i will do that asap and post the results

Comment: it is really strange! When i select 6 items the programm copies 3.. When i select 4 items the programm copies 2.. i don't know why